# Clear console output on *R* buffers when using ESS

Tags: ess, r, comint

I have this kbd in my `init.el`

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'comint-clear-buffer)
```

When I use Emacs-ess mode fro programming in R, I use this kbd to clear the R output buffer, this is usually called `*R*`. That works, but it requires that I go into the `*R*` buffer and do `C-l` from there.

Can this be modded so that wherever I am into some other buffer, the `comint-clear-buffer` command is applied specifically to the `*R*` buffer when I am into an ESS mode buffer?

Answer (score 1):

This switches to the R REPL buffer in its window, or in the the current one if no window is displaying it, and clears the screen.

```lisp
(defun my-r-clear-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (pop-to-buffer (ess-get-process-buffer) '((display-buffer-reuse-window
                                             display-buffer-same-window)))
  (comint-clear-buffer))

(define-key ess-r-mode-map (kbd "C-l") #'my-r-clear-buffer)
```

However, `C-l` is normally already bound to `recenter-top-bottom`, which is a pretty useful function. I suggest you to use

```lisp
(define-key ess-r-mode-map (kbd "C-c l") #'my-r-clear-buffer)
```

instead.

---

`(ess-get-process-buffer)` retrieves the R REPL buffer associated with the current R source code buffer. IOW, the function above clears the buffer that `C-RET` sends lines to.

This version should be more stubborn about finding an R REPL buffer to clear.

```lisp
(defun my-r-clear-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((r-repl-buffer (seq-find (lambda (buf)
                                   (string-prefix-p "*R" (buffer-name buf)))
                                 (buffer-list))))
    (if r-repl-buffer
        (pop-to-buffer r-repl-buffer '((display-buffer-reuse-window
                                        display-buffer-same-window)))
      (user-error "No R REPL buffers found"))
    (comint-clear-buffer)))
```

It just switches to the first buffer in the buffer list whose name begins with "*R" and clears that.

Note: the reason why I search for a buffer whose name begins with "*R" instead of just aiming at the buffer named `*R*` is that in my Emacs (v. 27.1, ESS v. 18.10) R REPL buffers have paths in their names, like `*R:~*`.

---

> it doesn't move back to the original associated buffer.

You just have to ask.

```lisp
(defun my-r-clear-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((r-repl-buffer (seq-find (lambda (buf)
                                   (string-prefix-p "*R" (buffer-name buf)))
                                 (buffer-list))))
    (if r-repl-buffer
        (with-current-buffer r-repl-buffer
          (comint-clear-buffer))
      (user-error "No R REPL buffers found"))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") #'my-r-clear-buffer)
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work, says: "No ESS process is associated with this buffer now"

Comment: @PinkCollins I've updated the answer

Comment: This one works althogh after cleaning the *R* process buffer it doesn't not move back to the original associated buffer.

Comment: Your kbd didn't work in my case, I don't know why. I did my usual way: ```(eval-after-load "ess-mode"
  '(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "C-c l") 'my-R-clear-buffer))``` and it now works

Comment: @PinkCollins If you want to be able to call the function from any buffer, in any mode, you have to bind it in the global map. See my updated answer. (If you read my now deleted comments, forget them, they didn't solve your problem.)

Comment: Your last version is great! Perhaps it would make sense to just retain to two best versions of the command (one of which is the last one)